# Can I use a Python/Ruby ORM inside C?

Tags: python, c, ruby

I have heard many times that C and Python/Ruby code can be integrated.

Now, my question is, can I use, for example a Python/Ruby ORM from within C?

Comment: Did you check out the documentation on [embedding python](http://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but the API would be unlikely to be very nice, especially because the point of an ORM is to return *objects* and C doesn't have objects, hence making access to the nice OOP API unwieldy.

Even in C++ is would be problematic as the objects would be Python/Ruby objects and the values Python/Ruby objects/values, and you would need to convert back and forth.

You would be better off using a nice database layer especially made for C.

Answer (score 2):

For Ruby, yes, you can by using the Ruby C API. After including `ruby.h` you can use [`rb_funcall`](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/Ruby_C_Extension_API_Documentation_%28Ruby_1.8%29#Invoke_Ruby_method_from_C):

> To invoke methods directly, you can use the function below
>
> ```
> VALUE rb_funcall(VALUE recv, ID mid, int argc, ...)
> ```
>
> This function invokes a method on the `recv`, with the method name specified by the symbol `mid`.

This will allow you to call *any* Ruby method, and thus use any Ruby code from C. It won’t be pretty, though. There are a lot of good resources in [SO’s Ruby C API tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-c-api/info).